# Raspeberry pi OTG power and usb pen drive

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb-otg

I know The OTG port is used to power the pi. So, how could I use a usb drive on that OTG port ? Could i plug a powered hub and the drive on the hub ? Moreover, is there any other way to power the pi while leaving the otg port to be used as a normal host usb port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the USB ports of the Raspberry Pi are OTG (see [USB on Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#universal-serial-bus-usb)). However the Micro-USB Type B connector I think you are refering to is simply for powering the device. Data lines are not connected anywhere there (refer to [schematics](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305080241/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf)).

As for the rest of the question I am actually not sure what's that about.